# Android error thrown when running the apk, but not in development mode

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin

I'm encountering a really strange issue. I'm working on an ejected expo, react-native application (with native android and iOS code) and until a couple of days ago, everything was fine. In the meanwhile I had to upgrade one of the used libraries **(com.virgilsecurity:ethree:2.0.6)**.

*The issue on android comes here*: In development mode, everything works as expected, no errors are shown, but when building a new APK and running it, I stumble upon this issue: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method b.g.b.j.b, parameter identity`.

The error is thrown from within the newly updated library, but I need this version. I've tried cleaning, rebuilding and invalidating the cache. I think that it has something to do with the **kotlin** version? But that's just an assumption and I'm not really used to android apps ...

Some more details about my environment:

- expokit - 34.0.2
- react-native 0.59.8
- targeted SDK 28

iOS application works like a charm, so it's not related to the server or other parts of the app.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Hammered this as a dupe of two different questions, as your question lacks a [mcve]. Deobfuscate the stacktrace, make an MCVE, and I'll consider reopening

Comment: I've tried deobfuscating, but because it's a 3rd party library the logs look the same. An MCVE would be hard to produce, that's why I've noted down the status of the project. I'm not looking here for a clear "do that and it will work", because I know it's hard or rather impossible. I'm looking for some points of direction because I'm running out of options.